# Good neural network topology and training method for image recognition

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, neural-network, image-recognition

I have already done a simple project on pattern recognition. 
I used Backpropagation and a multi-layer Neural network to recognize 10 alphabetical letters.
It was pretty hard and I had lots of trouble fighting local minimums and slow training.  
But still, this programme worked.
Of course, it could have been just my bad code :)

Right now I'd like to improve my results and use all 26 letters. Moreover the training data may be more complex (larger images at least). So I am a bit worried that I might use a wrong approach.
What do you think might help? 
Maybe I should use some sort of combination between genetic algorithms and Neural Networks?
Or use a more complex network topology? (Ward network and training algorithm come to mind)

I'd like to mention the fact that I am not using any OCR libraries, it's just an educational project.

It would be great if anyone could give me an advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try [resilient propagation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rprop) training.

I have had great success with vanilla Rprop training. As for ANN topology normal feed-forward works for image processing. You can try experimenting with [Self-organizing map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-organizing_map) if all the letters are of same font and small size (4x4 maybe), the output could represent letters.

Comment: This is great! Never heard of anything like that. It seems I'm stuck in old ANN manuals. As for topology, I wanted to use parallel programming to train different layers. Do you know anything about it?
Thank you very much

Comment: I tried parallel back propagation once but the threading overhead was too much, resulting program was 10~15 times slower. But another approach worked, calculating the change in weights for all the input-output set then adding them at the end. This takes lot of memory. Back propagation is not suitable for threading.